# Which tool can change file permissions recursively

Tags: web-hosting, file-manager

I need to change file and folder permission on remote linux web server recursively.

For fast uploading i zipped my files and uploaded that zip file. Later on i extracted zip file using file manager of hosting server. It unzipped files but ther file permissions we set to 600 for files and 700 for folders.

Now i need to change them 644 and 755 to all files and folders recursively. I do not want to check in folder by folder and change the permission. Is there any tool that can do that recursively?

Comment: do you have ssh access or just ftp?

Comment: no i do not have ssh access... just ftp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on FTP then your client should let you right click the folder to change the permissions and it should have a checkbox saying something like "Click here for a files and folders within".

If you are using SSH then you can use chmod -R 755.

Comment: filezilla is one client that can do this